# Lambda vs. (Action)delegate in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, dispatcher

What is the difference between calling a Lambda function and explicitly invoking a delegate in Dispatcher? In other words, what is the difference between the following:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action( () => Foo() ));

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate () { Foo(); });

private void Foo() { }
```

Comment: It is just a historical artifact.  Anonymous methods were added in C# version 2.  Gave them enough confidence and experience to consider adding the more universal lambda expression syntax in version 3.   Still using anon methods isn't that useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Both lines of code produce the same `MSIL code` (shown for example by `ILSpy`):

```
IL_000f: ldarg.0
IL_0010: call instance class [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject::get_Dispatcher()
IL_0015: ldarg.0
IL_0016: ldftn instance void WpfApplication2.MainWindow::'<.ctor>b__0_0'()
IL_001c: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Action::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_0021: ldc.i4.0
IL_0022: newarr [mscorlib]System.Object
IL_0027: callvirt instance class [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::BeginInvoke(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate, object[])
```

Answer (score 3):

no difference.

in both case you define a anonymous method to call foo();

note : can be done like this

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Foo);
```